# Использование PHP в готовом html

Tags: php, html5

Как можно подключить и использовать PHP в HTML. Я знаю что в самом PHP файле можно через echo'' написать необходимый HTML код, но тогда он для меня не очень удобен. Есть ли способ подключить PHP скрипты к готовому HTML? Если можно будет использовать PHP без перезагрузки страницы будет вообще шикарно.

UPD. Вопрос задал заранее, что бы была возможность получить ответ пока ищу такую же информацию в интернете.

Comment: переименовываете html в php, там где нужен именно php код пишите `<?php код ?>` все что вне этих тегов выводиться как есть. В итоге никакие echo не нужны. А что до 'без перезагрузки страницы', это решается по другому, выводить можете тот же html а в него добавляете javascript код который через методы ajax асинхронно обращается на сервер уже к php, которая отдает информацию для обновляемой области снраницы

Answer (score 1):

Меняете расширение файла с html на php и в нужных местах вставляете теги

```
<?php
   //тут пишите php код
?>
```

HTML с условиями:

```
<?php 
  if (условие) { 
?> 
  тут какой-то html код, который будет виден только если условие выполнено
<?php 
  } 
?>
```

Изменение страницы без её перезагрузки - это изучайте AJAX.

Comment: Спасибо большое, а можно ли в одном файле прописывать несколько <?php ?> ?

Comment: @DiDra да, можно сколько угодно. Допускаются даже разрывы условий PHP с вставками html кода. Типа так: <?php if (условие) { ?> тут html код <?php } ?>

Comment: @DiDra дополнил ответ

Comment: @nightflash лучше со скобками не пишите, если вдруг что-то потеряете, потом труднее найти будет. Правильнее будет писать `<? if(...): ?> ... <? endif; ?>` Тем самым сразу видно, что здесь именно блок if заканчивается, а не просто `}` не понятно к чему относится

Comment: @DmitriiSedov о, спасибо! Не знал о таком способе.

Comment: Я кстати ответ написал на эту тему. А ознакомиться с этим можно тут: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 1):

Дополнив ответ @nightflash хочу сказать что для шаблонов есть специальный синтаксис для управляющих конструкций [Альтернативный синтаксис управляющих структур](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Альтернативный синтаксис для некоторых его управляющих структур, а именно: `if`, `while`, `for`, `foreach` и `switch`. В каждом случае основной формой альтернативного синтаксиса является изменение открывающей фигурной скобки на двоеточие (:), а закрывающей скобки на `endif;`, `endwhile;`, `endfor;`, `endforeach;` или `endswitch;` соответственно.

Примеры

```
<?php if ($a == 5): ?>
A равно 5
<?php endif; ?>
```

или

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
Имя пользователя: <?= $user['name']; ?>
<?php endforeach ; ?>
```

В целом ничто не мешает писать html код без `echo`.